# Listings With Two or More Sets of Keywords

Tags: listings

I am looking for a way to create two different sets of keywords, because I want to assign each set of keywords a different color.

The language of the code I want to import, is not supported by the `listings` package. So far I did this in the preamble

```
\usepackage{listings}   
\lstset{
otherkeywords={*,myKeyword1,myKeyword2},  
keywordstyle=\color{purple}  
}
```

Is it possible to define two different sets of keywords, so that I can assign each set a different color?

Comment: I just found this [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199297/latex-create-a-second-keywordstyle-using-listing-doesnt-work], which works well!